# Mongoose findOneandUpdate is not adding all of the fields to the document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Ok, so I have burnt hours on this and multiple various google searches, and I can't seem to solve this.  So, I'm here for some help...

I am trying to use `mongoose.findOneAndUpdate()` to either add a document or update an existing document into a collection. I have done this many times before successfully, but I am stumped right now.

When the document is created in the mongodb it contains only this:

```json
{
  _id: <some mongo id>
  faFlightID: 4839-fjgnkbk-adhoc
  positions: [Array of Objects]  <----These appear to be correct.
}
```

That's it.  It is missing all of the other fields.  I feel like I am missing something completely and totally obvious, but at this point I've been staring at it for so long, I probably can't see the forest for the trees

Here is my mongoose code:

```js
const Flights = require('../models/faFlights.model');

const saveFlight = async (flight) => {
    let position = {
        timestamp: flight.timestamp,
        longitude: flight.longitude,
        latitude: flight.latitude,
        groundspeed: flight.groundspeed,
        altitude: flight.altitude,
        heading: flight.heading,
        altitudeStatus: flight.altitudeStatus,
        altitudeChange: flight.altitudeChange,
    };
    
    const filter = { faFlightID: flight.faFlightID };
    const update = { flight, $push: { positions: position } };

    try {
        let result = await Flights.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update {
            upsert: true,
            new: true,
        });
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

And here is my faflights.model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const positionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        set: (d) => formatEpoch(d),
    },
    longitude: Number,
    latitude: Number,
    groundspeed: Number,
    altitude: Number,
    heading: Number,
    altitudeStatus: String,
    altitudeChange: String,
});

const faflightSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        TALON_ACT_ID: String,
        faFlightID: String,
        ident: {
            type: String,
            set: (acreg) => modifyACRegistration(acreg),
        },
        prefix: String,
        type: String,
        suffix: String,
        origin: String,
        destination: String,
        timeout: Number,
        departureTime: {
            type: Date,
            set: (d) => formatEpoch(d),
        },

        firstPositionTime: {
            type: Date,
            set: (d) => formatEpoch(d),
        },
        arrivalTime: {
            type: Date,
            set: (d) => formatEpoch(d),
        },

        positions: [positionSchema],
        lowLongitude: Number,
        lowLatitude: Number,
        highLongitude: Number,
        highLatitude: Number,
        updateType: String,
        waypoints: String,
    },
    { collection: 'faflights' }
);

//Convert AC Registration formatting
const modifyACRegistration = (reg) => {
    let firstCharacter = reg.substring(0, 1);
    let remainingCharacter = reg.substring(1, 5);
    return `${firstCharacter}-${remainingCharacter}`;
};

const formatEpoch = (epoch) => {
    if (!epoch) return;
    return new Date(epoch * 1000);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('faflights', faflightSchema);
```

I am at a total loss.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I just needed to leave my workstation for a while, or more coffee...or both.  Needed to use $set to make it all better.

```
    const filter = { faFlightID: flight.faFlightID };
    const update = { $set: flight, $push: { positions: position } };

    try {
        let result = await Flights.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update {
            upsert: true,
            new: true,
        });
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```